# Time span subtract stopwatch countdown

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer, subtraction

I'm using WinForm's. I have a label in my form that should count down from 0:20 seconds. to 0:00 seconds. I'm trying to do this here, but the compiler gives me an error.

> Error: Cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.TimeSpan'

Why cant I use timespan.Subtract()? and how could I count down from 0:20 to 0:00 seconds?

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan timespan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        Time_label.Text = timespan.Subtract(stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds);
    }
```

Comment: Note that `stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds` is only the seconds *component*, so it counts from 0 to 59 then rolls back over to 0 again. You might want `stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds` which keeps counting passed 59. Unless you are making a cock for display I find it rare that people actually want `Seconds` and not `TotalSeconds`.

Comment: You don't need to use a `StopWatch`. You need to use just a timer, but when you want to start the timer, first calculate the `EndTime` or `StopTime` and then start the timer. In each tick, you should update the text of label and also check if you reached the end time, then stop the timer and show `00:00` on label. You may find this post useful: [Display time elapsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420596/display-time-elapsed) - I believe it's an exact duplicate.

Comment: You event don't need to use `TimeSpan`, take a look at linked post and set the end time by `endTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(20);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach for a simple second counter would be to make use of the `Timer` itself.

```
private readonly Timer _timer;    
private TimeSpan _timespan;
private readonly TimeSpan _oneSecond;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _timer = new Timer();
    _timer.Tick += timer1_Tick;
    _timer.Interval = 1000;       

    _timespan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
    _oneSecond = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);

    _timer.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (_timespan >= TimeSpan.Zero)
    {
        Time_label.Text = _timespan.ToString(@"m\:ss");
        _timespan = _timespan.Subtract(_oneSecond);
    }
    else
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: My label wont count down/ or update though it stays at 00:00:19 seconds

Comment: If it says "00:00:19" your code is not "copied" correctly since my example will say "0:20" (as per your expected result) when starting.

Answer (score 2):

`stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds` returns and `int`, specifically, the number of seconds. `timespan.Subtract(TimeSpan)` accepts a TimeSpan object.

You can try:

```
Time_label.Text = 20 - stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds;
```

or

```
Time_label.Text = timespan.Subtract(stopwatch.Elapsed).Seconds;
```

**Please note** there is a flaw in your logic. You restart a new stopwatch everytime you fire the tick event, so everytime it fires you have a new 0:00 stopwatch and you will get 19 or 20 in the textbox.
Instantiate your stopwatch elsewhere so it is the same between ticks.

EDIT:
as suggested by a Quantic's comment, if you plan on having more than a minute worth of seconds

```
Time_label.Text = (int)timespan.Subtract(stopwatch.Elapsed).TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: Upvote for your edit adding the other implementation.  stopwatch.Elapsed is a timespan which is parameter of timespan.Subtract. No casting needed.

Comment: `.TotalSeconds` is safer. `.Seconds` is only the "Seconds component" and is only between 0 and 59.

Comment: @Quantic Nice, also TotalSeconds is a double and will be more precise than an int32.

Comment: @Quantic True. but original question was very specific. Could be he'd also want a formatted string with hours and minutes but that is conjecture.

Comment: @taji01you have a flawed logic in the tick event. watch updated answer

Answer (score 1):

TimeSpan.Subtract expects another TimeSpan struct. The Stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds is an Int32 struct. There isn't any built in implicit conversion to convert an Int32 to TimeSpan. You could try this

```
Time_label.Text = timespan.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(stopwatch.Elapsed.seconds)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

TimeSpan.Subtract expects that you subtract another instance of TimeSpan from it (TimeSpan in itself is not bound to a specific time unit, so by subtracting say "15" it doesn't "know" what unit you have in mind).

What you want is either

```
Time_label.Text = Timespan.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds)));
```

which produces a rather nifty preformatted

```
00:00:20
```

Or (taking advantage of the fact that Stopwatch's Elapsed is a TimeSpan itself)

```
Time_label.Text = timespan.Subtract(stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

But that produces

```
00:00:19.9999765
```

which is probably too precise to display to an end user (it's caused by Stopwatch being precise down-to-a-tick).