# Adding time to timer with button click

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a timer set up, but can't work out how to add time by using buttons to add 10 seconds, 1 minute and 10 minutes respectively. I'm not sure if I've managed to get it to count down correctly, as I copied code from a timer that counted up and tried to reverse it. Any help would be much appreciated. 
Here's my code:

```
    int Ten_Sec = 10000;
    int One_Min = 60000;
    int Ten_Min = 600000;
    System.Timers.Timer t ;
    int hour, min, sec;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t = new System.Timers.Timer();
        t.Interval = 1000; //1sec
        t.Elapsed -= OnTimeEvent;
    }

    private void Button_Ten_Sec_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ten_Sec++;
    }

    private void Button_One_Min_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        One_Min++;
    }

    private void Button_Ten_Min_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ten_Min++;
    }

    private void OnTimeEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Invoke (new Action(() =>
        {
            sec -= 1;

            if (sec == 60)
            {
                sec = 0;
                min -= 1;
            }

            if (min == 60)
            {
                min = 0;
                hour -= 1;
            }

            textBox_Timer.Text = String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", hour.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), min.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), sec.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));


        }));
    }
```

Comment: [Display elapsed time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38420844/3110834)

Comment: it looks like you are unsubscribing from the OnTimeEvent in the Form_Load... is that intentional?

Comment: Honestly it's not as it was just in code I saw for making a count up timer

Comment: take a look at my answer for an example.

Comment: @ephtee How would I prevent the timer from going past zero (negative) or have it to let me carry out an action at certain time intervals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few basic things to know about at timer:

1. It has a `Tick` event (or an `Elapsed` event, depending on the timer you're using). It raises this event on a regular basis. You can subscribe one or more methods to this event, and they will be triggered at regular intervals
2. It has an `Interval` - this is the nubmer of milliseconds it waits before raising the `Tick` event.
3. It has an `Enabled` property. If this is set to false, the timer is not running.
4. It has a `Start` method. Call this method to start the timer. It also has a `Stop` method that you can call when you want it to stop. These methods also set the `Enabled` property, so if you call `Stop`, then `Enabled` will be set to `false`.

Looking at your code from top down, the first thing I would do is get rid of these variables. They aren't doing anything, and the `TimeSpan` class already has an easy way to specify a number of minutes or seconds:

```
// We don't need these
int Ten_Sec = 10000;
int One_Min = 60000;
int Ten_Min = 600000;
```

Also, you are using a `System.Timers.Timer`, which may cause some troubles when trying to update the control text, since it runs in another thread. Instead, let's use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
```

We could also use a variable to hold the time that we're displaying. If we make this a class-level variable, then we can change it both from the timer's `Tick` event as well as from buttons that the user clicks:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
    TimeSpan countdownClock = TimeSpan.Zero;
```

Now, in your `Form_Load`, you're doing the right things, except you are un-subscribing the `OnTimeEvent` from the timer. If anything, we should be subscribing to the event instead, so we have some code to execute when the timer elapses.

Also notice I renamed your timer from `t` to `timer`. It increases readability and doesn't really slow down coding since Visual Studio gives intellisense as soon as you type `t`. And I used the `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` method to set the timer interval, which makes it more obvious what the interval is:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer.Interval = (int) TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).TotalMilliseconds;
    timer.Tick += OnTimeEvent;
    DisplayTime();
}
```

You might be wondering what `DisplayTime()` is there for. I wrote a small function to display the time on the form, since we're doing it from more than one place and it has a specific format string. Now that this is done in one place, if you want to change the format, there's only one place to change the code.

Also, I noticed that you were using a `TextBox` to display the time, but for a read-only value, it's probably better to use a `Label`. I created one named `lblTime`:

```
private void DisplayTime()
{
    lblTime.Text = countdownClock.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
}
```

Now, in answer to one of your main questions: How do we stop the timer when it gets to `0`? We can do this in the `OnTimeEvent` event, since this is the moment when the timer is reading the current countdown clock and removing a second from it.

Notice that the signature of this method is slightly different than yours. Since I'm using a different type of timer, the requirements are different:

```
private void OnTimeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Subtract whatever our interval is from the countdownClock
    countdownClock = countdownClock.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timer.Interval));

    if (countdownClock.TotalMilliseconds <= 0)
    {
        // Countdown clock has run out, so set it to zero 
        // (in case it's negative), and stop our timer
        countdownClock = TimeSpan.Zero;
        timer.Stop();
    }

    // Display the current time
    DisplayTime();
}
```

So the only thing left to do is enable the timer. Since we're starting at `0`, there is no where to count down to, but you appear to have some buttons on your form for adding time to the clock, so let's use those.

Because we'll be updating the time from multiple places, and this also requires a check to see if the timer is disabled and to start it if it isn't, I created a helper method to add time to the clock:

```
private void AddTimeToClock(TimeSpan timeToAdd)
{
    // Add time to our clock
    countdownClock += timeToAdd;

    // Display the new time
    DisplayTime();

    // Start the timer if it's stopped
    if (!timer.Enabled) timer.Start();
}
```

Now, in each button we'll just call that function, passing a different span of time depending on which button was pressed:

```
private void Button_Ten_Sec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add ten seconds to our clock
    AddTimeToClock(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
}

private void Button_One_Min_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add one minute to our clock
    AddTimeToClock(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
}

private void Button_Ten_Min_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add ten minutes to our clock
    AddTimeToClock(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
}
```

Hopefully that's enough to get you going. You now have a countdown timer that will stop when it gets to `0`, and which you can add time to from your buttons.

Comment: You legend I appreciate this so much, means I can pretty much finish my program

Comment: There was a bug that the initial time wasn't displaying when adding time to the clock, which I just fixed in the `AddTimeToClock` method (which was simply to call `DisplayTime` before starting the timer

Comment: Say I wanted to reduce the time between timer execution (i.e. effectively make the countdown run faster) how would I go about this? I've played about with the timer.Interval line, but can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Re read the answer, it has all the information you need. Unless you mean you want to display the time differently, like show milliseconds?

Comment: I've re-read and read again, and I know it's in the timer.interval, and normally you'd just change the int value, but I don't understand what all the stuff on the right means?

Comment: Set the `Interval` to the number of milliseconds you want it to wait before triggering the `Tick` event. If you're going to make the interval less than a second, then you'll want to display the milliseconds. That can be done by adding a `\.ffff` to the end of the format string where we display the time. You can use 1-7 `f` characters, which specifies how many digits of miliseconds to display. I don't know what you mean by "stuff on the right".

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) structure. You can manipulate them to output whatever amount of time you want as well as adding and subtracting time from it. Given your example, you may want to use `TimeSpan`

```
    TimeSpan testTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Start();

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testTime = testTime.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
        lblTime.Text = testTime.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testTime = testTime.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
        lblTime.Text = testTime.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testTime = testTime.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));
        lblTime.Text = testTime.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testTime = testTime.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
        lblTime.Text = testTime.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
    }
```

which results in the following:[image]